# Deduction fails

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I declared a global shift operator but for some reason the compiler cannot deduct the type.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& stream, std::array<T, N>& array);
```

Instead it tries to use a overload with `std::istream&&` as the first argument.

EDIT: I invoke via

```
void myns::subns::Object::Func(std::istream& stream) {
  stream >> array;
}
```

where array is `std::array<size_t, 2>`.
Indeed, when I try it isolated it compiles - but in my code gcc (4.7) complains `error: cannot bind ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’`

Could someone explain to me why the deduction does not work or how I can force to call the function overload?

Comment: How do you _try_ to invoke it?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/n2D5o

Comment: @mfontanini Thanks. I do not understand why it works isolated.

Comment: What namespace are you declaring the `operator>>` in and in what namespace are you invoking it?

Comment: @DaveS `operator>>` has no namespace (global) and I invoke it from `mynamespace::subnamespace` where `Object` is declared in.

Comment: OMG it works using `::operator>>(stream, array);`! Ok, I obviously do NOT understand C++ anymore.

Comment: @LCIDFire: ADL doesn't work on templates, so it won't find it when its cross namespace.

Comment: @Dani - ADL works for templates, but the global namespace isn't searched here.

Comment: Adding additional operators to objects you do not own is always tricky (read impossible). The standard way of declaring free operators is to declare them in the namespace of the arguments and in the case of `std` this is explicitly forbidden by the standard. The lesson here is, that you better just not do it. Think of the users of your code and the implications if someone else tries to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesn't find the `operator>>` in the namespace it is called from, the compiler looks for the operator in namespaces associated with the parameters you use. In this case they all come from namespace std, and not from the global namespace. Therefore the global namespace is not searched.

When you explicitly call `::operator>>(istream, array)`, it *does* look in the global namespace (as you specifically asked it to).

Comment: So the correct thing to do here is to derive a wrapper class from the `std` Collection and then write a namespace specific operator?

Comment: Probably, yes. Printing standard containers is tricky, as they don't have any `operator>>` overloads. Making them members and print the enclosing type is a possible solution.